# Munchkin Booty Ships are 'items', but are Ship Enhancers permanently bound to the ship?

Tags: munchkin

[According to the rule book](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/rules/booty_rules.pdf):

1. Ships are Items, and follow normal Item rules.
2. There are also a few Items that specifically enhance Ships.
3. A Ship with an Enhancer has the Enhancer’s gold value added to its own.
4. Enhancers cannot be moved between Ships.

Reading this, I would expect enhancers to be permanently attached to the ship. So if the ship is stolen, the enhancers are also stolen with it. Also, enhancers cannot be stolen off the ship separately, as that would a) have no point (rule #4) and b) have their value now attached to the ship (rule #3).

Is that a correct read?

Answer (score 1):

As *Ships* are big items, they cannot be stolen by any version of [the rules](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/rules/booty_rules.pdf) I am familiar with (from ***Ships*** on *page 5*):

> The “Big” designation on Ships is to control
>   what Traps and Curses affect them, and to keep Thieves in a
>   blender game from pocketing them and walking off.

While I cannot find a specific rule or faq to verify it, my interpretation of the second query is the same as yours, for the same reason, as items that are *ship enhancers* have this text on them:

> enhancers cannot be stolen off the ship separately; ...

However, it is less clear to me whether *ordinary item enhancers* must obey the same rule. They do not have the standard text for *steed/ship enhancers* (from ***Ships*** on *page 5):

> ...; it follows the Steed[/Ship] if it is lost, stolen or discarded

In the absence of a FAQ stating otherwise, I would apply the same rule as for *ship enhancers* on the basis that the common text above from *Steed/Ship Enhancers* ***does not say*** "this enhancer"; it says the far more general "enhancers".